# Having trouble witth imgkit

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf, imgkit

I am quite a noob when it comes to python. So there is probably quite a simple solution to this.

I am trying to capture screenshots of webpages using imgkit. However, when running the script in pycharm, I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\PycharmProject\websitescreenshot\venv\lib\site-packages\imgkit\config.py", line 30, in __init__
    with open(self.wkhtmltoimage):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/name/PycharmProject/websitescreenshot/Test.py", line 3, in <module>
    imgkit.from_url('https://pypi.org/project/imgkit/', 'out.jpg')
  File "C:\Users\name\PycharmProject\websitescreenshot\venv\lib\site-packages\imgkit\api.py", line 31, in from_url
    cover_first=cover_first)
  File "C:\Users\name\PycharmProject\websitescreenshot\venv\lib\site-packages\imgkit\imgkit.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.config = Config() if not config else config
  File "C:\Users\name\PycharmProject\websitescreenshot\venv\lib\site-packages\imgkit\config.py", line 36, in __init__
    'http://wkhtmltopdf.org\n'.format(self.wkhtmltoimage))
OSError: No wkhtmltoimage executable found: "b''"
If this file exists please check that this process can read it. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - http://wkhtmltopdf.org


Process finished with exit code 1
```

the code:

```
import imgkit

imgkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.jpg')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Hi Pedro, the code is very simple so far - I have added the code above

Answer (score 2):

You see the crash because `wkhtmltopdf` is missing from `PATH` variable or it's not installed on your system. It should work after installing the tool via your package manager.

For Ubuntu run:

```sh
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```